# Summation Recurrence Relation

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, cauchy-product

How to solve this Summation Recurrence Relation: $$x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix_{n-i}\,,\,\,\,n\ge1$$where, $x_0=1$ and $a_n$ is some arbitrary sequence.

The right hand side of the recurrence looks partially like a discrete convolution and also like Cauchy's Product. I tried using Generating Functions, but I don't think they work because of the pesky $a_n$.

Comment: If $F(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i t^{i}$ and $G(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i t^{i}$  then $F(t)=(1+F(t))G(t)$ so $F(t)=\frac {G(t)} {1-G(t)}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Oh yes, it should be $a_i$. Changed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can  solve   the  recurrence relation using generating functions. In order  to  keep the things somewhat simpler we assume $a_0=0$.

> As    reference for later we calculate the first few elements $x_n, n=1,2,3$. We obtain from 
>   \begin{align*}
> x_0=1, x_n=\sum_{j=1}^n a_jx_{n-j}\qquad n\geq 1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   the first few elements as follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{x_1}&=\sum_{j=1}^1a_jx_{1-j}=a_1x_0\color{blue}{=a_1}\\
> \color{blue}{x_2}&=\sum_{j=1}^2a_jx_{2-j}=a_1x_1+a_2x_0\color{blue}{=a_1^2+a_2}\\
> \color{blue}{x_3}&=\sum_{j=1}^3a_jx_{3-j}=a_1x_2+a_2x_1+a_3x_0\\
> &=a_1(a_1^2+a_2)+a_2a_1+a_3\color{blue}{=a_1^3+2a_1a_2+a_3}
> \end{align*}

Let
\begin{align*}
A(t)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jt^j\qquad\qquad B(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x_kt^k
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(t)B(t)}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+j=n}\atop{k,j\geq 0}}a_jx_k\right)t^n
> =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=0}^na_jx_{n-j}\right)t^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{j=1}^na_jx_{n-j}\right)t^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}x_nt^n\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=B(t)-1}
> \end{align*}
>
> *Comment:*
>
> - In (2) we start the indices from $1$ by using the assumption $a_0=0$.
> - In (3) we use the recurrence relation (1).
>
> It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B(t)=\frac{1}{1-A(t)}}
> \end{align*}

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[t^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^n$ of a series $C(t)$.

> We obtain for $n\geq 1$
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{x_n}&=[t^n]B(t)
> =[t^n]\frac{1}{1-A(t)}=[t^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(A(t)\right)^j\\
> &=[t^n]\sum_{j=1}^n\left(a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots a_nt^n\right)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=[t^n]\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{{l_1+l_2+\cdots+l_n=j}\atop{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n}\geq 0}
> \binom{j}{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n}\prod_{q=1}^na_q^{l_1}t^{l_1+2l_2+\cdots+nl_n}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{{{l_1+l_2+\cdots+l_n=j}\atop{l_1+2l_2+\cdots+nl_n=n}}\atop{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n\geq 0}}
> \binom{j}{l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_n}\prod_{q=1}^na_q^{l_q}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we restrict the upper limit of the series with $n$ since higher powers of $A(t)$ do not contribute to $[t^n]$. We also take only the first $n$ summands of the series $A(t)$ up to $a_nt^n$ since other summands do not contribute to $[t^n]$.
- In (4) we apply the *[multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)*.
- In (5) we finally select the coefficient of $t^n$.

> We calculate the first elements $x_n, n=1,2,3$ according to (5) as small plausibility check. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{x_1}&=\sum_{j=1}^1\sum_{l_1=j}\binom{j}{l_1}\prod_{q=1}^1a_q^{l_q}=\binom{1}{1}a_1^1\color{blue}{=a_1}\\
> \color{blue}{x_2}&=\sum_{j=1}^2\sum_{{{l_1+l_2=j}\atop{l_1+2l_2=2}}\atop{l_1,l_2\geq 0}}\binom{j}{l_1,l_2}\prod_{q=1}^2a_q^{l_q}
> =\binom{1}{0,1}a_1^0a_2^1+\binom{2}{2,0}a_1^2a_2^0\\
> &=\frac{1!}{0!1!}a_2+\frac{2!}{2!0!}a_1^2\color{blue}{=a_2+a_1^2}\\
> \color{blue}{x_3}&=\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{{{l_1+l_2+l_3=j}\atop{l_1+2l_2+3l_3=3}}\atop{l_1,l_2,l_3\geq 0}}\binom{j}{l_1,l_2,l_3}\prod_{q=1}^3a_q^{l_q}\\
> &=\binom{1}{0,0,1}a_1^0a_2^0a_3^1+\binom{2}{1,1,0}a_1^1a_2^1a_3^0+\binom{3}{3,0,0}a_1^3a_2^0+a_3^0\\
> &=\frac{1!}{0!0!1!}a_3+\frac{2!}{1!1!0!}a_1a_2+\frac{3!}{3!0!0!}a_1^3\color{blue}{=a_3+2a_1a_2+a_1^3}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> in accordance with the calculation at the beginning.

Comment: Awesome solution! Thank you!

Comment: @Shashank: You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_nt^{n}$ and $G(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nt^{n}$. Then $F(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix_{n-i}t^{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\sum_{n=i}^{\infty} x_{n-i}t^{n-i})a_it^{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_{n}t^{n}+x_0)a_it^{i}=(F(t)+1)G(t)$ hence $F(t)=\frac {G(t)} {1-G(t)}$.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the problem we have $A\cdot X = X$,  displayed in matrix-arrangement

$$ \begin{array}{}
  & * & \left [\begin{array}{} 1 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 
    \end{array} \right] \\
 \left [ \begin{array}{} 1 \\ a_1 &0 \\ a_2 & a_1 &0 \\ a_3 & a_2 & a_1 &0
    \end{array} \right ]
  & = &\left [\begin{array}{} 1 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 
    \end{array} \right ]
\end{array} \tag 1 $$
This is, btw. an Eigenvector-problem: if we subtract on the left matrix ***A*** the identity we get $(A - I) \cdot X = 0 $ or in matrix-display
$$ \begin{array}{}
  & * & \left [\begin{array}{} 1 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 
    \end{array} \right] \\
 \left [ \begin{array}{} 0 \\ a_1 &-1 \\ a_2 & a_1 &-1 \\ a_3 & a_2 & a_1 &-1
    \end{array} \right ]
  & = &\left [\begin{array}{} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 
    \end{array} \right ]
\end{array} \tag 2$$
We can now separate the constant expression with the first column in $A-I$ from the rest and write

$$ \begin{array}{}
  & & * & \left [\begin{array}{}  x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 
    \end{array} \right] \\
\left [\begin{array}{}  a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 
    \end{array} \right] +  &  \left [ \begin{array}{}  -1 \\  a_1 &-1 \\ a_2 & a_1 &-1
    \end{array} \right ]
  & = &\left [\begin{array}{}  0 \\ 0 \\ 0 
    \end{array} \right ]
\end{array} \tag 3 $$
Let us denote the left column-vector as ***B*** and the left square-matrix as ***C*** then we have
$$ \begin{array}{rl} B + C\cdot X& = 0 & \text{and can rearrange for solving} \\
   C \cdot X &= - B \\
   X &= - C^{-1} \cdot B \end{array} \tag 4
$$

***Solution:*** Using the symbolic feature in Pari/GP this gives (I used $x_1 ... x_4$ here)
$$  \begin{array} {}
 \left[\begin{array} {rrrr}
    a_1  \\ 
    a_1^2+a_2  \\ 
    a_1^3+2 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_1+a_3  \\ 
    a_1^4+3 \cdot a_2 \cdot a_1^2+2 \cdot a_3 \cdot a_1+a_2^2+a_4  \\ 
 \end{array} \right]& = &
 \left[\begin{array} {rrrr}
     x_1 \\ 
     x_2 \\ 
     x_3 \\ 
     x_4 \\ 
 \end{array} \right]
 \end{array} \tag 5
$$