Transform recursive formula to iterative formula
Let $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}\ }$ be some real series, $\gamma > 0$ and
$$
b_{i} = \gamma
\sum_{j=0}^{i - 1}a_{i - j}\,b_{j}
\quad\mbox{with}\ b_{0} = \gamma
$$

Is there a way to calculate $b_i$ without recursion ?.
I thought about finding a series $c_{i,j}\ $ that can be a recursive and independent of $b_{i}$, so that I can write
$$
b_{i} =
\sum_{j=0}^{i}c_{j}\,\gamma^{j + 1}
$$
Do you have any idea ?. I am thankful for a hint.


You may be interested in this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704352/summation-recurrence-relation

First hint: Replacing $a_i$ by $a_i/\gamma$ we may assume that $\gamma = 1$
Second hint:
The compositions of $4$ are

$1+1+1+1$
$1+1+2$, $1+2+1$, $2+1+1$
$2+2$
$1+3$, $3+1$
$4$

And $b_4 = a_1^4+3\ a_1^2\ a_2+a_2^2+2\ a_1\ a_3+a_4$
Do you see the pattern?
In general one can write $b_i$ as a sum over the compositions of $i$, which is a kind of sums that often appear in combinatorics.

Yeah I see the pattern. But how to determine an expression for $c_{i,j}$ and how to prove this formula?

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{b_{i}} & =
\color{#44f}{\gamma\sum_{j=0}^{i - 1}a_{i - j}\,b_{j}} =
\gamma\pars{\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_{i - j}\,b_{j} - a_{0}\,b_{i}}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{With}\quad \left\vert\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{c_{ij}} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{a_{i - j}}
\\
\ds{\Lambda} & \ds{\equiv} & \ds{{1 \over \gamma} + a_{0}}
\end{array}\right\}\quad
\\ & \mbox{you'll get an}\ \underline{Eigenvalue\ Equation}\quad
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\sum_{j = 0}^{i}c_{ij}\,b_{j} = \Lambda\, b_{i}}} \ &  
\end{align}
